# Angular $routeProvider not routing to nested directories

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im having problems using routeProvider to route to a subdirectory url.
The Following Angular route works fine:

```
$routeProvider.when('/customerapi', {templateUrl: 'partials/customerApi.html', controller: 'customerApiController'});
```

but when I attempt to do the following:

```
$routeProvider.when('/projects/customerapi', {templateUrl: 'partials/customerApi.html', controller: 'customerApiController'});
```

everything breaks. I get the following error[image: error message]

I know it can find the partial, it finds it fine when the route is just /customerapi...

Im unsure why its trying to load projects/partials/customerApi.html instead of angular intercepting and loading the partial. The  tag I am using to link to the partial looks like the following :

```
<a href="/projects/customerapi">Customer API</a>
```

Anyone happen to see my error?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the absolute path of the partial (note the `/` in front of `templateUrl`):

```
$routeProvider.when('/projects/customerapi', {templateUrl: '/partials/customerApi.html', controller: 'customerApiController'});
```

Comment: Thanks, worked! Didn't realize it was using the route path as a reference for the template! Thanks for lending another set of eyes! Greatly appreciated!